# How can I do Tuple sorting

Tags: python, sorting, tuples

```
Enter your name, age & score: a 17 99

Enter your name, age & score: a 19 98

Enter your name, age & score: a 19 100

Enter your name, age & score: a 19 99

Enter your name, age & score: b 19 99

Enter your name, age & score: b 19 98 

Enter your name, age & score: b 19 100

Enter your name, age & score: -1
```

The output:

```
(('a', '17', '99'), ('a', '19', '100'), ('a', '19', '98'), ('a', '19', '99'), ('b', '19', '100'), ('b', '19', '98'), ('b', '19', '99'))
```

The output should be like this:

(('a', '17', '99'), ('a', '19', '98'), ('a', '19', '99'), ('a', '19', '100'), ('b', '19', '98'), ('b', '19', '99'), ('b', '19', '100'))

How can I do that? Here's my code..

```
def check(txt):
    global c
    if txt.count(" ") == 2:
        tup=(tuple(txt.split(" ")))
        list1.append(tup)
        list1.sort()
    else:
        if txt != "-1":
            c= 1
            return c 
main() # prints the converted list to tuple..
```

Comment: I'm unclear on how you're attempting to sort them.

Comment: what are the rules to getting that output? your output doesn't make any sense to me

Comment: i'm sorry i already edit the errors there. it should be 98 99 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted)

```
sorted(your_tup, key=lambda x: [x[0], int(x[1]), int(x[2])])
```

Comment: i tried this and worked. but i don't really get how this works haha

Comment: sorted will take  a  `key` ==> `specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a comparison key from each list element`. Here  before it compare key convert  2nd  and  3rd  item in the  each element  to int.

Comment: First, do you understand why the original output was as it was?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel i think i do

Answer (score 1):

The tuples are sorted correctly since they only contain strings. If you want to sort numerically, store the values as integers:

```
parts = txt.split(" ")
list1.append(tuple(parts[0], int(parts[1]), int(parts[2]))
```